# Cannot pass Token to Header Node JS

Tags: javascript, mongoose, header, basic-authentication

I am currently working on a BasicAuth for a Node Js application.

The */authenticate* route is to create a bearer token if the user is admin. I have tested it with this:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/authenticate
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIz
```

The created token should now be passed to the header so that further requests to the */user* route can clarify whether the user is authorized or not.

I have prepared the following tests for this purpose:

```
### list all users without token (should fail!)
http://localhost:8080/user

### list all users with token (should work!)
http://localhost:8080/user
Authorization: {{adminToken}}
```

This is my method for creating a token. The token is created *but not returned to the header*. **Why ?**

**function basicAuth**

```
function basicAuth(req, res, next) {
    
    if (!req.headers.authorization || req.headers.authorization.indexOf('Basic ') === -1) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Missing Authorization Header'
        });
    }

    // verify auth credentials
    const base64Credentials = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const credentials = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    const [username, password] = credentials.split(':');
    console.log("AuthenticationService " + username + " " + password);

    userService.findUserById(username, function(error, user) {

        user.comparePassword(password.toString(), function(err, isMatch) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Fehler")
                throw err;
            }
            /*Passwort richtig*/
            if (isMatch) {

                
                console.log("Passwort richtig. Token wird erstellt.")
                    var issueAt= new Date().getTime();
                    var expirationTime= config.get('session.timeout')
                    var expiresAt=issueAt+(expirationTime * 1000);
                    var privateKey = config.get('session.tokenKey');
                    let token =jwt.sign({"user": user.userID}, privateKey, {expiresIn: expiresAt, algorithm: 'HS256'});
                    console.log("Token erstellt: " +token);
                    user.token = token;
                res.send(token);

            }
            /*Passwort falsch*/
            if (!isMatch) {

                res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Passwort und userID stimmen nicht überein.'
                });



            }
        });
    })
}
```

This is my method to check if a token was passed and if this token is correct:

**isAuthenticated**

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (typeof req.headers.authorization !== "undefined") {
    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    console.log(token)
    var privateKey = config.get('session.tokenKey');
    jwt.verify(token, privateKey, { algorithm: "HS256" }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Not Authorized. No token." });
    return;
    }
    return next();
    });
    } else {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Not Authorized" });
    return;
    }
    }
```

Finally, I hang the whole thing in the route and want to get a result.

```
router.get('/user',authenticationService.isAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {

    userService.getUsers(function(err, result) {
        console.log("Resultat: " + result)
        if (result) {
            res.send(Object.values(result))
        } else {
            res.send("Es gab Probleme.")
        }
    })

})
```

Comment: You're not putting the token in the headers; you're attaching it to the `user` object (which is fine by me)

Comment: how to I put the token to the header ?

Comment: `res.set('token', 'YWRtaW46MTIz');` ?

Comment: I changed the code to your suggestion, but `http://localhost:8080/user
Authorization: {{adminToken}}` still doesn't work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work" ?

Comment: `POST http://localhost:8080/authenticate Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIz` is passing me back a token -as expected. `POST http://localhost:8080/authenticate Authorization: Basic admin:1234` is passing me back nothing - as expected. `http://localhost:8080/user` is passing me back an "Not authorised"-error - as expected and `http://localhost:8080/user
Authorization: {{adminToken}}`is passing me back an "Not authorised"-error -**but it should pass me all users**

Comment: But is it because you get no token? Or because your token is invalid? Both return `{ error: "Not Authorized" }` so it's hard to tell the difference

Comment: I changed the if/else of the _isAuthenticated_-function to see if a token was passed - no a token was not passed.

Comment: If I `console.log(req.headers.authorization)` in the _function isAuthenticated_ I get: `{{loginAdminCorrect.response.headers.Authorization}}
{
  'user-agent': 'vscode-restclient',
  authorization: '{{loginAdminCorrect.response.headers.Authorization}}',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  host: 'localhost:8080',
  connection: 'close'
}`  Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have significantly stripped down the *isAuthenticated* function. Now it works:

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
        const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
      
        if (bearerHeader) {
          const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
          const bearerToken = bearer[1];
          req.token = bearerToken;
          next();
        } else {
          // Forbidden
          res.status(500).json({ error: "Not Authorized" });
        }
      }
```